# Is the forking repo deleted when the forked repo has been deleted on github?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo on github. If the forked repo has been deleted, is my branch of the repo deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not unless it's a private repo:**

> Be warned: Deleting a private repo will delete all forks of the repo.
>   Deleting a public repo will not.

-- https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repo